# Is this integral convolution continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, convolution

The following question is related to the one in [Is this convolution continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454843/is-this-convolution-continuous/4454917#4454917)

Let $0 \leq \xi \leq T$, $Y_0 \in  L^2([-T, T])$, $a_1 \in L^2([0,T])$ and consider the following function:
$$
Y_{1}(\xi)=\int_{0}^{\xi} a_{1}(\alpha) Y_{0}(\alpha-\xi) d \alpha
$$
Now if inside the integral $Y_0$ did not depend on $\xi$ then $Y_1$ would be absolutely continuous. Instead in the case I describe is $Y_1$ continuous? The difference with the other question is that here I only require $Y_0 \in \mathcal L^2([-T, T])$ and not $Y_0$ being continuous$.

Inspired by [The convolution of two $L^2(\mathbb R)$ functions is continuous](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2915085/the-convolution-of-two-l2-mathbb-r-functions-is-continuous) I could proceed in the following way by a density argument:
Let $Y_0^n \to Y_0$ in $L^2([-T, T])$ where $Y_0^n$ are continuos functions. Then by defining $Y_1^n(\xi)$ with $Y_0^n$ in place of $Y_0$ we have that $Y_1^n(\xi)$ is continuous (actually uniformly continuous, see [Is this convolution continuous?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4454843/is-this-convolution-continuous/4454917#4454917) ).

Finally we show that $Y_1^n \to Y_1$ uniformly on $\xi \in [0,T]$, i.e.
\begin{align}
|Y_1^n(\xi)-Y_1(\xi)|^2 &=\left |\int_0^\xi a_1(\alpha)[Y_0^n(\xi-\alpha)-Y_0(\xi-\alpha)] d \alpha \right|^2\\
& \leq \int_0^\xi a_1(\alpha)^2 d \alpha \int_0^\xi [Y_0^n(\xi-\alpha)-Y_0(\xi-\alpha)]^2 d \alpha \\
& \leq \int_0^T a_1(\alpha)^2 d \alpha \int_0^T [Y_0^n(\xi-\alpha)-Y_0(\xi-\alpha)]^2 d \alpha\\
& = |a_1|_{L^2} \int_{\xi-T}^{\xi} [Y_0^n(x)-Y_0(x)]^2 d \alpha\\
& \leq |a_1|_{L^2} \int_{-T}^{T} [Y_0^n(x)-Y_0(x)]^2 d \alpha \to 0
\end{align}
where the convergence is uniform wrt $\xi \in [0,T]$.

Now we conclude that $Y_1$ is continuous as uniform limit of continuous functions.

Is everything correct?

Comment: Indeed, I did the exercise to quickly, and made some mistakes...

Comment: Anyway as I was saying should be correct, consider: \begin{align*}
   \big|Y_1(\zeta) - Y_1(\xi)\big|&= \bigg| \int_0^\zeta a_1(\alpha)Y_0(\alpha+\zeta) \mathrm{d}\alpha - \int_0^\xi a_1(\alpha)Y_0(\alpha+\xi) \mathrm{d}\alpha \bigg|
\\
&\le  \int_0^\zeta \big|a_1(\alpha)\big| \big|Y_0(\alpha+\zeta) - Y_0(\alpha+\xi)\big| \mathrm{d}\alpha + \int_\zeta ^ \xi |a_1(\alpha)||Y_0(\alpha+\xi)| \mathrm{d}\alpha \end{align*}

Comment: The first term on the rhs goes to zero by dominated convergence and the second by Holder's inequality so it is continuous, do you agree? Uniform continuity I'm not sure

Comment: yes it's correct, however, without a continuity assumption on $Y_0$ unfortunately, you can't conclude.

Comment: You mean I cant conclude the uniform continuity without the contiuity assumption?

Comment: You can't conclude on the continuity of $Y_1$ without the assumption that $Y_0$ is continuous.

Comment: Hi @Surb you were right. I uptdated the question showing a possible way. Do you agree now?

Comment: Notice that continuous function are dense in $L^2$, so you can always take a sequence of continuous function $(Y_0^n)$ s.t. $Y^n_0\to Y_0$ in $L^2$ (it's not a supplementary assumption). I don't see any mistake in your proof, so it's correct to me (and indeed, no need continuity of $Y_0$). And congratulation for your determination ! Despite the fact that I said that it doesn't work, you proved me that I was wrong :-D (I should have been more careful and say that it may not work ^^). So (+1)

Comment: Great, thanks for the check and remark!